# Running "replace contractions" across all text files in same directory and output to multiple text files in another directory

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner user of Python.

I am writing a Python script using "replace contractions" to replace contractions in all text files in the same directory with the expanded words, and then outputting the replaced files to another directory.

The code looks like the following at present:

```
import re, string, unicodedata
import nltk
import contractions
import inflect
import os

txt_files = [f for f in os.listdir('./test') if f.endswith('.txt')]

fd = open(txt_files)
with open(txt_files)as fd:
    fd.method
    fd.close()

def replace_contractions(text):
    """Replace contractions in string of text"""
    return contractions.fix(text)

output_strings = map(replace_contractions, txt_files)  
output_content = "".join(sorted(output_strings))  # sort join the output strings without separators

# write to file
with open(folder_path + output_filename, 'wt') as outfile:
    outfile.write(output_content)
```

The error which I have received is:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Text Preprocessing.py", line 9, in <module>
    fd = open(txt_files)
TypeError: invalid file: ['1.txt', '2.txt']"
```

Can anyone advise me on resolving the error? Thank you!

I have now edited my code to the following:

```
import re, string, unicodedata
import nltk
import contractions
import inflect
import os

txt_files = [f for f in os.listdir('./test') if f.endswith('.txt')]

import glob
for each_file in glob.glob("arc\.\d+\.txt"):
    print(each_file)

def replace_contractions(text):
    """Replace contractions in string of text"""
    return contractions.fix(text)

output_strings = map(replace_contractions, txt_files)  
output_content = "".join(sorted(output_strings))  # sort join the output strings without separators

# write to file
folder_path = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test1\\'
output_filename = os.path.join(folder_path, '.txt')
with open(output_filename, 'wt') as outfile:
    outfile.write(output_content)
```

There is no error. But I have 2 output files. The first is a text file with the string "1.txt2.txt" inside the text file and the second file has a filename as an underscore and is without any extension. I am not getting the desired output in the txt files, i.e. to expand the contractions in the text inside the txt files. Can anyone help out?

Comment: "txt_files" holds a list of files, but "open" expects a single file. You should use "txt_files[index]", probably in a loop.

BTW, if you are using Python 3.4 or newer, you might want to consider to use the "pathlib" module instead of the "os" module.